# Ruby gem watir changing Firefox proxy settings without being asked to

Tags: firefox, proxy, watir

For whatever reason, watir changes my Firefox browser settings without my instruction to do this.

If I open Firefox manually (at the office), it normally is set to 'No Proxy' and works just fine.

*However, if watir launches a new FF instance, it is set to 'Manual Proxy', and a a browser error states that it's trying to use a proxy server which is refusing connection.*

We have no proxy server at work.

How do I get watir to launch a Firefox window with No Proxy?  I've searched the web and have not found a single example of this.

(BTW, the FF settings from a watir-launched session are independent of normal FF settings; in other words, manually changing FF settings doesn't correct the problem).

Comment: This question is about Firefox not starting as expected when using the 'Watir' gem in Ruby. Therefore, I do not think it should be considered as "off-topic".

Comment: I agree. Browser profile settings are an everyday topic in 'Watir' testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the information [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.proxy.type#5_5), there are 5 different proxy configurations for Firefox:

```
0
Direct connection, no proxy. (Default in Windows and Mac previous to 1.9.2.4 /Firefox 3.6.4)
[edit]
1
Manual proxy configuration.
[edit]
2
Proxy auto-configuration (PAC).
[edit]
4
Auto-detect proxy settings.
[edit]
5
Use system proxy settings. (Default in Linux; default for all platforms, starting in 1.9.2.4 /Firefox 3.6.4)
```

It looks like "0" is the one you need.  We set that as described on the [Watir-Webdriver help page for Firefox](http://watirwebdriver.com/firefox/):

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile["network.proxy.type"] = 0
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```

All of the profile["lorem ipsum"] type options are listed in the about:config menu URL in Firefox, and are accessed/changed in a similar fashion.

Comment: That code snippet works beautifully, and it resolves my issue.  Much thanks!  This will help out my teammates as well.

Comment: I'm still wondering what proxy mode "3" does since the official documentation skips that number...